# How to export video faster

Tags: video

back when I used hitfilm 
it export video 10 min in 6 min
but when I'm using blender it takes up to 12 min
is there any way to export it faster

Comment: What do you mean by *"export"*? Encoding? Please provide more details.

Comment: to add on to poor's comment, or do mean render?

Comment: @Karim - don't get me wrong, but you won't get any useful answers as long as you drop oneliners. What **exactly** are you trying to do? You have one video in format X and try to export it to format Y? If so, please specify X and Y. Good questions will result in good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to see you have all these downvotes. I've done a lot of research on this and i'll provide info I have found that has worked for me.

File > User Preferences > System

- Audio Dev [SDL]
- Images Draw Method [GLSL or DrawPixels]
- Sequencer / Clip Editor > Memory Cache Limit [Set appropriate to your machine]

In a blender window, properties pane

- Display [Keep UI]

  - This will cause blender to not pop up a rendering window and such.

Keep in mind that things you do in the editor will impact times. Adding a color correction for instance doubles my time.
Blender is also not geared towards being a full video editor and thus isn't as optimized as a dedicated one such as hitfilms. Still gets the job done.